# The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: DELETE

Tags: php, laravel

I got this error when I try to remove subcategories by however I did use the delete method.

**blade.php:-**

```
 <form action="{{ url('sub_category/delete',$item->id) }}" method="DELETE">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-danger">remove category</button>
 </form>
```

my web

```
 Route::DELETE('/sub_category/delete/{id}','SubcategoryController@destroy');
```

**controller:-**

```
 public function destroy($id)
{
    $subcategory= Subcategory::where('id',$id)->delete();

    return redirect()->route('cars.index');
                    // ->with('success','Car deleted successfully');
}
```

Comment: you have to use "form method spoofing" as the HTML forms only support GET/POST ...   https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#form-method-spoofing

Answer (score 0):

DELETE,PUT,PATCH,HEAD methods should be defined as follows

> @method('DELETE') @method('PUT') ...

[Laravel routing](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing)

```
<form action="{{ url('sub_category/delete',$item->id) }}" method="POST">
@method('DELETE')
@csrf
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-danger">remove category</button>
</form>
```

Comment: i had this error instead The DELETE method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

Answer (score 0):

Your form should be in the following way

```
<form action="{{ url('sub_category/delete',$item->id) }}" method="POST">
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">
@csrf
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-danger">remove category</button>
</form>
```

Comment: why should i put  input in the form

Comment: Since there is not a DELETE method on forms, it must be masked through an input field. The same occurs with PUT.

Comment: i had this error now The DELETE method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

Comment: can you try lowercasing your method in route definition? `Route::delete`and then call php artisan route:list to check if your delete route is defined?

Answer (score 0):

try like this one:

```
 <form action="{{ url('sub_category/delete',$item->id) }}" method="POST">
     {{method_field('DELETE')}}
     @csrf
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-danger">remove category</button>
 </form>
```

your route:

```
Route::delete('/sub_category/delete/{id}','SubcategoryController@destroy');
```